# How to allow CORS in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, post

I'm trying to do an ajax post request from my web app to my ASP.NET endpoint (everything locally) to insert data in my database but I'm always getting `POST http://localhost:44326/radar/insertConfig net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

What I've gattered so far: The endpoint works perfectly when called via Insomnia;
I have other GET requests working perfectly in the same conditions (same page, same domains, etc);
I have tested my POST request to a public endpoint and everything worked fine; The request never leaves the browser (or never reaches the destination). **The issue only happens when sending a POST request to my API from my web application.**

What I've tried: using another browser (Chrome, Edge, Firefox), deleting cookies, clearing cache, reseting my connections, reseting my computer, trying from a different connection.

Note1: I'm using a VPN and an antivirus that I cannot turn off (neither).

Note2: When done via firefox the error becomes: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:44326/radar/insertConfig. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

My request:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
var url = "http://localhost:44326/radar/insertConfig";
$.post(url, json, function (status) {
    if (status == "success")
        alert("yay");
    else
        alert("nay");
}, "json");
```

The line at which the error happens: `plugins.bundle.js:9838`

```
xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );
```

What could be the possible problem?

Update: I added a middleware in my server that looks like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            await next.Invoke();
        });
```

But if I do that, then the return becomes 415 (unsupported media type). I tried to fix that by changing my request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: json,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (status) {
        if (status == "success")
            alert("yay");
        else
            alert("nay");
    }
});
```

But then again, the CORS error returns...

Comment: try using a relative path...  (if you must use absolute try with https and/or 127.0.0.1)

Comment: You'll need to update your service's (ASP.NET endpoint) CORS configuration to accept requests from your localhost domain. I think for testing purposes, you can set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to accept request to any origin, but I'll suggest to set it up properly afterwards. Here's the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @pcalkins that didn't work, but using https made this error return instead `Access to
XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44326/radar/insertConfig' from origin 'https://localhost:44301' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: @nmina That kind of worked, I added a middleware for that but then this error happened instead: `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change some stuff for this to work, here was my solution:

step 1: add this to the ConfigureServices and Configure (by default they're in the Startup.cs)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: "MyPolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    //This is how you tell your app to allow cors
                    builder.WithOrigins("*")
                            .WithMethods("POST", "DELETE", "GET")
                            .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
}
```

step 2: Change the request to $.ajax instead of $.post

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: json,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

from the error message it looks like your client and your server are from different domains, in order to be able to call your server from a different domain you need to enable CORS on your server.

for a asp.net server you can use `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` nuget package and add `EnableCors` attribute on your controller as follow
`[EnableCors(origins: "http://{your-client-domain}", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

Comment: That kind of worked, I added a middleware for allowing cors in the response header but then this error happened instead: `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: there is an extra `,` in your header name

Comment: That was a typo, thanks. But still, the error persisted...

Comment: where exactly have you added the middleware in your pipeline order ? and also can you see the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response headers when you query you server from the browser in the same domain ?